# JBoss Serialization and `NoClassDefFoundError`

Tags: scala, serialization, jboss

I'm trying to use `JBoss Serialization` to store my objects and this is my helper for this:

```
object JBoss {
  def toBytes(exe: Any) = {
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val oos = new JBossObjectOutputStream(baos)
    (oos writeObject exe, oos flush, oos close, baos close)
    baos.toByteArray
  }

  // Object in byte form
  type ByteObj = Array[Byte]

  def to[T](exe: ByteObj) = {
    val bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(exe)
    val ois = new JBossObjectInputStream(bais)
    val rs = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[T]
    ois.close
    rs
  }
}
```

When I try to use it like so:

```
try {
  class A(val x: String, s: String) { override def toString = s"A(x = $x, s = $s)" }
  val bytes = JBoss.toBytes(new A("one", "two"))
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => println(e)
}
```

I get the following exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/TObjectHashingStrategy` How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are missing libs at runtime.
You should use lib trove-2.1.1.jar add to your classpath when run project.

[Trove download here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/trove/trove/2.1.1)